# Get return data of field date as current date

Tags: postgresql

I want to return all entries that are entered today does not matter the time I use this to insert

```
INSERT INTO hangfire.job(stateid, statename, invocationdata, arguments, createdat, expireat, updatecount)
VALUES (44, 'Schedule', 'Test Invocation data', 'Test arguments', now()::timestamp, null, 0);
```

And use this to retrieve the data but it returns nothing only the fields

```
SELECT * From hangfire.job WHERE createdat = now()::timestamp;
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: `now()::timestamp` can be simplified to `localtimestamp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A timestamp contains a time (as the name indicates), if you want to ignore that time, use a `date`:

```
SELECT * 
From hangfire.job 
WHERE createdat::date = current_date;
```

If you have an index on createdat the above will not use that index. If you need that for performance reasons, use a range condition:

```
SELECT * 
From hangfire.job 
WHERE createdat >= current_date
  AND createdat < current_date + 1;
```